# Import all modes in brace

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browserify, ace-editor

I'm trying to make an editor where one can choose the mode before starting the program. I'm using the npm packages `react-ace` and `brace` for my project. The problem is, that the brace documentation suggests importing the modes one using e.g. `import 'brace/mode/java';`, but I ideally want to support all ace modes.
Does anyone know whether this is possible?

Comment: you could use ace directly, since it has a way to lazy load modes and themes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I didn't come up with a better solution, but here's what works for me.

Please note that these 143 imports sum up to 6+ MB.

editor.js:

```
import 'acemodes'
/*
...
*/
```

acemodes.js:

```
/*
cmd to reproduce: ls node_modules/brace/mode/ | awk '{split($9, s, "."); print "import \"brace/mode/"s[1]"\";"}'
*/

import 'brace/mode/ada';
import 'brace/mode/apache_conf';
import 'brace/mode/applescript';
import 'brace/mode/asciidoc';
import 'brace/mode/assembly_x86';
import 'brace/mode/autohotkey';
import 'brace/mode/batchfile';
import 'brace/mode/bro';
import 'brace/mode/c9search';
import 'brace/mode/c_cpp';
import 'brace/mode/cirru';
import 'brace/mode/clojure';
import 'brace/mode/cobol';
import 'brace/mode/coffee';
import 'brace/mode/coldfusion';
import 'brace/mode/csharp';
import 'brace/mode/css';
import 'brace/mode/curly';
import 'brace/mode/dart';
import 'brace/mode/django';
import 'brace/mode/d';
import 'brace/mode/dockerfile';
import 'brace/mode/dot';
import 'brace/mode/drools';
import 'brace/mode/eiffel';
import 'brace/mode/ejs';
import 'brace/mode/elixir';
import 'brace/mode/elm';
import 'brace/mode/erlang';
import 'brace/mode/forth';
import 'brace/mode/fortran';
import 'brace/mode/ftl';
import 'brace/mode/gcode';
import 'brace/mode/gherkin';
import 'brace/mode/gitignore';
import 'brace/mode/glsl';
import 'brace/mode/gobstones';
import 'brace/mode/golang';
import 'brace/mode/groovy';
import 'brace/mode/haml';
import 'brace/mode/handlebars';
import 'brace/mode/haskell_cabal';
import 'brace/mode/haskell';
import 'brace/mode/haxe';
import 'brace/mode/hjson';
import 'brace/mode/html_elixir';
import 'brace/mode/html';
import 'brace/mode/html_ruby';
import 'brace/mode/ini';
import 'brace/mode/io';
import 'brace/mode/jack';
import 'brace/mode/jade';
import 'brace/mode/java';
import 'brace/mode/javascript';
import 'brace/mode/jsoniq';
import 'brace/mode/json';
import 'brace/mode/jsp';
import 'brace/mode/jsx';
import 'brace/mode/julia';
import 'brace/mode/kotlin';
import 'brace/mode/latex';
import 'brace/mode/less';
import 'brace/mode/liquid';
import 'brace/mode/lisp';
import 'brace/mode/logiql';
import 'brace/mode/lsl';
import 'brace/mode/lua';
import 'brace/mode/luapage';
import 'brace/mode/lucene';
import 'brace/mode/makefile';
import 'brace/mode/markdown';
import 'brace/mode/mask';
import 'brace/mode/matlab';
import 'brace/mode/maze';
import 'brace/mode/mel';
import 'brace/mode/mushcode';
import 'brace/mode/mysql';
import 'brace/mode/nix';
import 'brace/mode/nsis';
import 'brace/mode/objectivec';
import 'brace/mode/ocaml';
import 'brace/mode/pascal';
import 'brace/mode/perl';
import 'brace/mode/pgsql';
import 'brace/mode/php';
import 'brace/mode/powershell';
import 'brace/mode/praat';
import 'brace/mode/prolog';
import 'brace/mode/properties';
import 'brace/mode/protobuf';
import 'brace/mode/python';
import 'brace/mode/razor';
import 'brace/mode/rdoc';
import 'brace/mode/rhtml';
import 'brace/mode/r';
import 'brace/mode/rst';
import 'brace/mode/ruby';
import 'brace/mode/rust';
import 'brace/mode/sass';
import 'brace/mode/scad';
import 'brace/mode/scala';
import 'brace/mode/scheme';
import 'brace/mode/scss';
import 'brace/mode/sh';
import 'brace/mode/sjs';
import 'brace/mode/smarty';
import 'brace/mode/snippets';
import 'brace/mode/soy_template';
import 'brace/mode/space';
import 'brace/mode/sql';
import 'brace/mode/sqlserver';
import 'brace/mode/stylus';
import 'brace/mode/svg';
import 'brace/mode/swift';
import 'brace/mode/tcl';
import 'brace/mode/tex';
import 'brace/mode/textile';
import 'brace/mode/toml';
import 'brace/mode/tsx';
import 'brace/mode/twig';
import 'brace/mode/typescript';
import 'brace/mode/vala';
import 'brace/mode/vbscript';
import 'brace/mode/velocity';
import 'brace/mode/verilog';
import 'brace/mode/vhdl';
import 'brace/mode/wollok';
import 'brace/mode/xml';
import 'brace/mode/xquery';
import 'brace/mode/yaml';
import 'brace/mode/abap';
import 'brace/mode/abc';
import 'brace/mode/actionscript';
import 'brace/mode/lean';
import 'brace/mode/live_script';
import 'brace/mode/livescript';
import 'brace/mode/mavens_mate_log';
import 'brace/mode/mips_assembler';
import 'brace/mode/mipsassembler';
import 'brace/mode/swig';
import 'brace/mode/diff';
import 'brace/mode/plain_text';
import 'brace/mode/text';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used on my `Vue` project, hope it helps :

```
require('brace/mode/' + mode);
```

This line is called every time the mode changes.

You need some piece of code somewhere that will know the full list of brace modes tho so it's able to let the user select it in a list.

Once you know the name of the mode you want you're all good.

Plus, require will only load the same file once, even if called several times.

I couldn't figure out how to load the list from `Brace`, the few solutions I found online are for `Ace` only and I wasn't able to adapt them to `Brace`.

I just copied, cleaned, and saved the mode list from the top answer here.